# How to get a working absolute path for a working url in require() in php on localhost

Tags: php, localhost, require

I have been struggling with this half an evening yesterday. I want to make a constant I can use to create the first part of an url string in php. I have tried several approaches, yet none of the seem to work as I hoped.

Let's assume this folder structure:

```
--someRandomlyNamedMap
  -- PHP
    -- libraries
      -- myLib1
        -- Class1.php
        -- Class2.php
    -- executionCode
      -- MyCodeThatUsesLibraries.php
  -- CSS
  -- initialiseConstants.php
```

**Try 1:**

I started referring to an url with relative paths. This works. But once I refer to another file in the file I refer to the path will be incorrect and everything will come crashing down.

MyCodeThatUsesLibraries.php

```
require('../libraries/Class1.php');
```

Class1.php

```
require('Class2.php'); // causes wrong file to load if called from MyCodeThatUsesLibraries.php
```

**Try 2:**

Okay, so I needed to take another approach. I figured I could refer to the root to get a constant to create absolute paths in my php code.

initialiseConstants.php

```
define( LIBRARY_ROOT, 
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/someRandomlyNamedMap/PHP/libraries');
```

MyCodeThatUsesLibraries.php

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/initialiseConstants.php');
require(LIBRARY_ROOT.'/Class1.php');
```

Class1.php

```
require('Class2.php');
```

Now I will get a new error message like (I recreated the urls in this to match the expample):

> Warning: require_once(....\myLib1\Class1.php): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in
>   E:\wamp64\www\someRandomlyNamedMap\PHP\libraries\myLib1\Class1.php
>   on line 3

When I load `E:\wamp64\www\someRandomlyNamedMap\PHP\libraries\myLib1\Class1.php` in my browser it does however output the php file it refers to (in text). So their is something going on here.

**Try 3:**

I figured try2 did not work because it should start the url with `http://localhost` and not a path to a file on my pc. So I google some and found `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. That seemed to output `localhost`, but not the `http://`-part. So the file would not load.

**Try 4**

To make up for the lack of `http://` I decided to add that to the string in the root.

initialiseConstants.php

```
define('LIBRARY_ROOT', 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/test/debiteuren/php');
```

MyCodeThatUsesLibraries.php

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/initialiseConstants.php');
require(LIBRARY_ROOT.'/Class1.php');
```

Class1.php

```
require(LIBRARY_ROOT.'/Class2.php');
```

This seemed to work (but only after changing php a setting called allow_url_include to On). Now there is some new weirdness. It loads the file I need.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Class2' not found in
>    E:\wamp64\www\someRandomlyNamedMap\PHP\libraries\executionCode\executionCode.php:20 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>    E:\wamp64\www\someRandomlyNamedMap\PHP\libraries\executionCode\executionCode.php on line 20

If I put an echo in the `Class1.php`-file it will be output if that file is accessed by `executionCode.php`. But I still get the above error where my `executionCode.php` can not use the class that is defined in `Class1.php`.

All of this leads me to ask this question:

**How to get a working absolute path for a working url in require() in php on localhost?**

PS: I would also like to know why some of the attempts I made did not work (especially try 4).

Comment: I use `define('WEBROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));`

Comment: You can use relative path (Try 1), but you'll need to use the `__DIR__` constant between your files. Eg: `require(__DIR__.'/Class2.php');`

Comment: `define('WEBROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)))` and `__DIR__` seem to give an url based on the location of the file in my PC. It will give an error simular to the one in try 2.